# sentence as user input - multiple times from terminal - bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to send lines from terminal to a text file multiple times using the following script. After writing the first line and its description in 2nd line, the script asks user whether he wants to enter another line or not. If yes, then user writes the 3rd line, 4th line and so on...

my problem is that after 2nd line, i.e. starting from 3rd line, the script writes only the first word, not the full sentence. How do I solve this ?

```
function ml() {
  echo $@ >> $HOME/path/to/file/filename
  echo -n "Enter description and press [ENTER]: "
  read description
  echo -e '\n[\t]' $description >> $HOME/path/to/file/myfile
  while true
  do
     read -p "Add another line?y?n" -n 1 -r
     echo -e "\n"
     if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
     then
         echo -n "Enter another line and press [ENTER]: "
         read -a meaning 
         echo -e "[\t]" $meaning >> $HOME/path/to/file/myfile
     else
         break
     fi
  done
  echo % >> $HOME/path/to/file/myfile
}
```

also I would like to have another modification in the code

```
read -p "Add another line?y?n" -n 1 -r
```

instead of asking y/n input, can it be done that after inserting the first two line, every ENTER will ask for another line input and pressing ESCAPE will terminate the script?

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your second call to `read`, you are using the `-a` argument which does:

> The words are assigned to sequential indices of the array variable aname, starting at 0.  aname is unset before any new values are assigned.  Other name arguments are ignored.

That appears to be not what you want.